# PowerPivotGallery View Issue For HTTPS Web Application-Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.ReportGallery.ReportGalleryView'

Tags: https, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

I have a Web application in SharePoint 2013 which is HTTPS. I have powerpivot installed and it is working fine when I try to access the PowerPivot Gallery with the port number.

For e.g. https://servername:45176/sites/bi/pp2/Forms/Gallery.aspx. Everything is working fine.

But when I try to accesss the same  https://servername/sites/bi/pp2/Forms/Gallery.aspx without port number I am getting the error.

Appreciate any help or pointer to fix the issue.

---

"Sorry, something went wrong Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.ReportGallery.ReportGalleryView'.

Correlation ID: 
 4ef61a9d-6ec4-d0c8-efd5-070a86f751a5

---

CorelationID details as given below.

Application error when access /sites/bi/pp/Forms/Gallery.aspx, Error=Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.ReportGallery.ReportGalleryView'.   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData)

System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.ReportGallery.ReportGalleryView'.    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData)

Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.ReportGallery.ReportGalleryView'. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.ReportGallery.ReportGalleryView'. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.ReportGallery.ReportGalleryView'.

at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)     at 
 System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()     at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)     at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Regards

Sakti

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved.

Here goes the solution:
If the web application is running on any other port apart from 443 (as the case here is the we app was running under: **https://servername:45176**/)then please deploy the solution "**powerpivotwebapplication.wsp**" on the web application running on port 443.

For me it resolve the issue and the PowerPivot Gallery start rendering without the error.

Regards
Sakti